# Demistrify Crash Report

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

[image]i am getting crash after approx 30-40 minutes..what i am doing is calling an api continusally in seprate thread **Dispatch Thread** i am not sure what crash report is indicating.. some snaps of crash report are

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x053639c0
Crashed Thread:  5

code i am using for this is

```
 ASIFormDataRequest *request=[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

    NSLog(@"%@",app.userName);
    [request addPostValue:app.userName forKey:@"username"];
    [request addPostValue:app.token forKey:@"token"];
            [request setTimeOutSeconds:40];
    [request startSynchronous];
if (!error)
{
if(not accurate value)
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5       target:self selector:@selector(checkCourse) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
else
{
  //got value 
}

}
```

Comment: Showing a stack trace of thread 5 might be useful.

Comment: @PhillipMills i added screenshot of thread 5.

Comment: If you can, if it is possible, you should not use ASI, is not supported anymore, better switch to AFNetworking of MKNetworkKit.

Comment: @Andrea i have used asi in whole project ..so please give suggestion regarding calling an api with 2-3 second interval..

Comment: Instead of asking for suggestions on how to use another SDK, you should read the documentation yourself. ASIHttpRequest should NOT be used any longer.